# Exclude domain from username when using autotype in Keepass

Tags: firefox, keepass

I have my Windows credentials stored in Keepass, where the username is set to `domain\username`.
Most places I log in to don't care if I type `username` or `domain\username`, however, I have one website that only works with `username`, and another that only works with `domain\username`. For the first one, I now manually remove `domain\`, which is not that much work, but I wonder if there's an easier way.

I see two options. One would be to add a special sequence to the context menu in Keepass, in the *Perform Autotype >* submenu. Is that possible? The other would be to somehow configure the Kee plugin in Firefox (my main browser), but I haven't been able to find out if that's possible.

Obviously, I don't want to store my credentials twice, with only different usernames.

Comment: As a side thought... shouldn't all those websites be picking up your Windows credentials automatically via Kerberos? (Set `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris` to `https://` via about:config.)

Comment: @u1686_grawity In the ideal world, yes